# How can I call Ajax function after check each check box in a list one by one in mvc 4 razor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to call an AJAX function based on checkbox checked in the `ul` which is listed below.  Based on `name="chkbrand_1"`, which is different for each checkbox,
ie. chkbrand_1, chkbrand_2, chkbrand_3 etc.

I'm getting a correctly value with this

```
   $('.searchType').click(function () {
                var checkboxName = $(this).attr("name");
                alert(checkboxName);
            });
```

but not getting a correctly value with this

```
 $('ul.chk li span').click(function () {
        var checkboxName = $(this).attr("name");
        alert(checkboxName);
    });
```

below is a result of Clint side page

```
<ul class="nav nav-list chk" id="brandnames">
    <li>
        <a style="padding-top: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="chkbrand_1" id="chkbrand" value="Intex" />
            <span style="cursor: pointer;">
                Intex 
                <span class="badge badge-info">4</span>
            </span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a style="padding-top: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="chkbrand_6" id="chkbrand" value="iPhone" />
            <span style="cursor: pointer;">
                iPhone 
                <span class="badge badge-info">5</span>
            </span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a style="padding-top: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="chkbrand_5" id="chkbrand" value="Nokia" />
            <span style="cursor: pointer;">
                Nokia 
                <span class="badge badge-info">3</span>
            </span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a style="padding-top: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="chkbrand_2" id="chkbrand" value="Samsung" />
            <span style="cursor: pointer;">
                Samsung <span class="badge badge-info">3</span>
            </span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a style="padding-top: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="chkbrand_3" id="chkbrand" value="Sony" />
            <span style="cursor: pointer;">
                Sony 
                <span class="badge badge-info">2</span>
            </span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a style="padding-top: 2px; padding-bottom: 2px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="chkbrand_4" id="chkbrand" value="Xolo" />
            <span style="cursor: pointer;">
                Xolo 
                <span class="badge badge-info">3</span>
            </span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Attach a `change()` event handler to the checkboxes and make a `$.ajax` call when the `checked` property is `true`. Also note that your HTML is invalid as you cannot  have an `input` inside an `a` element

Comment: I have updated my my question please review it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("input['type=checkbox']").on('change', function(e){ // event
   var checkboxName = $(this).attr("name"); //get checkbox name
   if(checkboxName == "chkbrand_4")
   {
      $.ajax(...) // your call
   }
});
```

**After OP edit.** If you need input `value` you should get it like this, [check fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/br5xn8tr/1/):

```
$('ul.chk li span').click(function () {
    var checkboxName = $(this).parent().find("input").val();
    alert(checkboxName);
});
```

Comment: var checkboxName = $(this).parent().find("input['type=checkbox']").attr("name"); is not getting alert

Comment: @Bikramjeet are you clicking on `span`?

Comment: @Bikramjeet then you should use `.val()` instead `.attr("name");`

Comment: like this  var checkboxName = $(this).parent().find("input").val().attr("name");

Comment: @Bikramjeet like this:  `$(this).parent().find("input").val()`

Comment: it same as i have to do in to get checkboxName value $('.searchType').click(function () {
                var checkboxName = $(this).attr("name");
                alert(checkboxName);
            });